# How to split a string based on a semicolon following a conditional digit

Tags: r

I'm working in R with strings like the following:

```
"a1_1;a1_2;a1_5;a1_6;a1_8"
"two1_1;two1_4;two1_5;two1_7"
```

I need to split these strings into two strings based on the last digit being less than 7 or not. For instance, the desired output for the two strings above would be:

```
"a1_1;a1_2;a1_5;a1_6"   "a1_8"
"two1_1;two1_4;two1_5"  "two1_7"
```

I attempted the following to no avail:

```
x <- "a1_1;a1_2;a1_5;a1_6;a1_8"
str_split("x", "(\\d<7);")
```

In an earlier version of the question I was helped by someone that provided the following function, but I don't think it's set up to handle digits both before and after the semicolon in the strings above. I'm trying to modify it but I haven't been able to get it to come out correctly.

```
f1 <- function(strn) {

  strsplit(gsubfn("(;[A-Za-z]+\\d+)", ~ if(readr::parse_number(x) >= 7) 
    paste0(",", sub(";", "", x))  else x,  strn), ",")[[1]]
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'd need to do to make this split as desired?

Comment: Are the numbers always increasing from left to right?

Comment: As far as I’ve observed, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting and recombining on `;`, with a simple regex capture in between.

```
s <- c("a1_1;a1_2;a1_5;a1_6;a1_8", "two1_1;two1_4;two1_5;two1_7")
sp <- strsplit(s, ";")

lapply(sp, 
  function(x) {
      l <- sub(".*(\\d)$", "\\1", x) < 7
      c(paste(x[l], collapse=";"), paste(x[!l], collapse=";"))
  }
)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a1_1;a1_2;a1_5;a1_6" "a1_8"               
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "two1_1;two1_4;two1_5" "two1_7"
```